# Aleatorizar mapa de Pacman, Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo que aleatorizar el mapa (un mapa diferente cada vez que se abre) de pacman cada vez que alguien empieza a jugar, no entiendo como podría hacerlo. por favor ayuda. Tengo una variable (world) que contiene el mapa estático, cuando se ejecuta la función drawWorld siempre crea ese mismo mapa, que en este caso es world, (en la variable worldDict se especifica que significa cada numero que conforman la variable world, estos estan asociados a una imagen que tengo en una carpeta, 0 es espacio vacio, 1 es pared, 2 es el sushi, 3 el onigiri), pero necesito crear uno diferente cada vez que se abre la página.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //mapa
  var world = [
    [1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,2,2,1],
    [1,2,1,2,1],
    [1,3,1,2,1],
    [1,2,2,3,1],
    [1,2,1,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1],
  ];
  var worldDict = {
    0: "blank",
    1: "wall",
    2: "sushi",
    3: "onigiri",
  }
//creacion de mapa
  function drawWorld(){
    output = "";
    for(var row = 0; row < world.length; row++){
      output += "<div class = 'row'>"
      for(var x = 0; x < world[row].length; x++){
        output += "<div class = '"+ worldDict[world[row][x]] +"'></div>"
      }
      output += "</div>"
    }
  
    document.getElementById("world").innerHTML = output;
  }
  drawWorld();
var ninjaman = {
  x:1,
  y:1
}
  var count = 0;
  var countsushi = 10;
  function drawNinjaman(){
    document.getElementById("ninjaman").style.top = ninjaman.y * 40 + "px"
    document.getElementById("ninjaman").style.left = ninjaman.x * 40 + "px"
  }
  drawNinjaman()

  document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
      if(world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x - 1] !=1){
        ninjaman.x--;
        if(world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x] == 2){
          count = count + countsushi;
        }
    }
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
      if(world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x + 1] !=1){
        ninjaman.x++;
        if(world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x] == 2){
          count = count + countsushi;
        }
      }
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
      if(world[ninjaman.y + 1][ninjaman.x] !=1){
        ninjaman.y++;
        if(world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x] == 2){
          count = count + countsushi;
        }
      }
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 38){
      if(world[ninjaman.y - 1][ninjaman.x] !=1){
        ninjaman.y--;
        if(world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x] == 2){
          count = count + countsushi;
        }
      }
    }
    world[ninjaman.y][ninjaman.x] = 0;
    drawNinjaman()
    drawWorld()
  }
  function totalcount(){
      document.write("!Genial¡, obtuviste " + count + " puntos");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay diferentes formas para randomizar los elementos dentro de un arreglo, una de ellas es el [Durstenfeld Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm), así que con este algoritmo podríamos randomizar lo que hay en tu arreglo de world, y luego randomizar cada una de sus posiciones. En la función array estoy implementando el shuffle, abajo sólo lo mando llamar para randomizar tu arreglo, y después hago un forEach para randomizar todos los arreglos de dentro

```js
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}

var world = [
    [1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,2,2,1],
    [1,2,1,2,1],
    [1,3,1,2,1],
    [1,2,2,3,1],
    [1,2,1,2,1],
    [1,2,2,2,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1],
  ];
  
  
shuffleArray(world);
world.forEach(element => {
    shuffleArray(element)
})

console.log(world)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo y responder, de verdad. con respecto al método que usaste, se debe incluir alguna librería para que funcione?

Comment: no, el "método" que usé, es un algoritmo usado para re-ordenar arreglos, simplemente lo que hace es cómo si fuera una baraja de cartas, cambia la posición de un elemento por otro, moviéndose de uno en uno